# How to add more stocks to a graph with twin axis's?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this code below to plt trends of stocks, and have 2 axis's one axis on the left and the other on right of the chart for 2 stocks with different scales.  I can't figure out how I can add more stocks to the graph.  I just have 2 stocks, but I like to add more.

How can I modify my code to add more stocks to the second axis?

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))

t = newdf['date']
s1 = newdf['IBM']

ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('Dates', fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xticklabels(t, rotation=45)
ax1.legend(loc=0)
ax1.grid()

# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = newdf['AAPL'] 

ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r-')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('date', colors='r', rotation=90)
ax2.legend(loc=2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[[image: Here is the graph with 2 axis's, with 2 stocks]]

[image]

Comment: You are looking for [parasite axes](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_parasite_axes2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-demo-parasite-axes2-py).

Answer (score 0):

> add more stocks just above fig.tight_layout() like this.
>       For nth stock add ax(n),s(n) and add stock name chose color from below link.

```
    ax3 = ax1.twinx()
    s3 = newdf[stock name] 
    ax3.plot(t, s3, 'r-')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Price', color=your color)
    ax3.tick_params('date', colors=your color, rotation=90)
    ax3.legend(loc=3)
```

> [Color](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)
>
> [RGB](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp)

Comment: Why would you plot in red and give your axes a different colour?

Comment: I added the code as you suggested.  How can I add the stock to an existing axis?  It appears there are three.  I like to add an additional stock to the the first axis.  Is that possible?